# Knockout: Determining which items in an array have been selected

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application

Or - Determining whether or not a given item has been selected.

I have an array of objects that can be "checked" - **if an item's checkbox is checked, some conditional attributes should be activated for the parent element (the color should change)**.  I have the conditional stuff and the checkboxes working, I just can't figure out how to efficiently monitor whether or not each item is currently selected.

My current implementation iterates over the "selectedItems" array to determine if it contains the target element, for each element.  I feel like this is the worst possible way to accomplish this:

```
var folderViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.isSelected = ko.computed(function () {
                var i = publishedSelectedFolders().length;
                debugger;
                while (i--) {
                    if (publishedSelectedFolders[i] === self.folderId()) {
                        alert("true");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }, self);
             .....
```

Any tips would be wonderful.  Here's my fiddle (simplified as much as possible):

http://jsfiddle.net/mWXTs/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it the other way around - use the [`checked`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) binding to bind to `isSelected` (instead of the array of selected items):

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected" />
```

On each folder:

```
self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
```

On the parent:

```
vm.selectedItems = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(vm.items(), function(item) {
        return item.isSelected();
    });
});
```